# save textfield on top of imageView (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, imageview

I would like to save a whatever is printed on top of the imageView. I tried to place 2 textfields over a imageView but its not saving.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiel1: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiel_2: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
              UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum((theImage.image)!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need take an screen shot of your view hierarchy

Comment: Your textFields are subViews of your ImageView?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need use the `drawHierarchy` method of your `UIImageView`, but first you need to be sure that all what you want to draw is subView of your desired view in this case your `UIImageView`

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.theImage.bounds.size)
self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.theImage.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
//you can do whatever you need with the image
```

Hope this helps you